# Use AJAX to report a server up or down?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm working on a page that tracks the reboot of a machine, and reports when it goes down, then reports when its back up

I created a small PHP page which prints 0 if the server pings and 1 if it doesn't

```
$SysName = strtoupper($_POST["SysName"]);
$ping = exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 $SysName", $input, $Presult);
echo $Presult;
```

Is there anyway to use AJAX to continually reload this page, checking the content for a 0 or a 1?

Answer (score 2):

You can use setInterval() to call your ajax function every t milliseconds:

```
window.setInterval(someAJAXfunction,milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$.ajax('YOUR-PHP-SCRIPT-URL').done(function(data){
  isUp = parseInt(data);

  // Do something with isUP
});
```

Comment: its somtimes difficult for me to see what Ajax is doing, so can you explain this? I just don't see how its checking the results of the page and continuing to check if its down... Do I need to implement the first Idea with this one?

Comment: This is just an example for a ajax call. Normally you would wrap this in a function and setTimeout